# Timezone in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, timezone

I have a simple booking scenario in which a user can book pre defined slots with some other user. The way i'm doing this is that i'm storing timeslots as array of strings using postgres. A typical array represents something like ["10:00PM", "10:30PM"]. However since different users are in different timezones so i'm using client to detect the timezone and show the slot in their respective timezones. My question is that is this sufficient to store the time slots and convert them into different timezones or do i need to store exact timestamp ?

Im using ruby and rails framewokr and postgres for db

Comment: Since you're using your time data as `string`s in an `array`, you're unavailable to use benefits of `datetime` data type in your DB. In this case, I'm not clear about what's your question really about?

Comment: i'm only interested in actual time conversion in different timezones, but what i was wondering was does it matter to have date info and does it make a difference in the accuracy of the conversion or not ?

Answer (score 2):

> i'm storing timeslots as array of strings using postgres

Don't. Please don't.

If they're concrete timestamps (date+time), store them as `timestamptz`, that way they're timezone independent. You can get them in user local time using the `AT TIME ZONE` operator or convert them client side.

If they're just times, use the `time` data type, and store them as UTC times, doing conversion to/from local time as appropriate using the `AT TIME ZONE` operator, or doing client-side conversion.

If possible, store them in a normalized table. If you can't do that for some reason (convince me) at least use a PostgreSQL array of the appropriate data type, not an array of strings - or worse, as it looks like you might be doing, a string representation of a Ruby array of strings.

This is a variant of an issue discussed on dba.stackexchange.com recently, discussing [whether native database types or a comma separated list would be better](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55871/postgresql-list-of-integers-separated-by-comma-or-integer-array-for-performance). The short version: do it a database friendly way unless you have a really, really, really good reason to do otherwise.